# How to make the search case insentitive in sparql?

Tags: sparql

I want to get all the resources in an ontology that include a given label. Let say we have a resource with the following label: Bill Gates.

So I write the following query in Sparql:

```
SELECT ?s
WHERE 
{
?s rdfs:label  ?description.
FILTER (CONTAINS(?description, "Bill Gates"))
}
```

Unfortunatley, I dont get this resource in response. If a just add in the query Bill (or Gates) instead "Bill Gates", I get the resource in response.

Indeed, How can I make the search case-insensitive? So let say, I have "Bill gates" or "bill gates" in my query while it is "Bill Gates" (or vice-versa" in the graph? I tried the following:

```
SELECT ?s
WHERE 
{
?s rdfs:label  ?description.
FILTER (CONTAINS(LCASE(?description), "bill gates"))
}
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach does work.  Perhaps the label isn't what you think it is, or the resource doesn't have the label?  Testing with `values` so that we can be sure of the data, the `lcase` approach works in this scenario (and regardless of language tags):

```
select * where {
  values (?s ?description) {
    (<urn:ex:a> "Bill Gates")
    (<urn:ex:b> "Bill Gates"@en)
    (<urn:ex:c> "Bill Gates"@en-us)
    (<urn:ex:d> "Gill Bates")
    (<urn:ex:e> "Gill Bates"@en)
    (<urn:ex:f> "Gill Bates"@en-us)
  }
  filter contains(lcase(?description), "bill gates")
}
```

produces

```
-----------------------------------
| s          | description        |
===================================
| <urn:ex:a> | "Bill Gates"       |
| <urn:ex:b> | "Bill Gates"@en    |
| <urn:ex:c> | "Bill Gates"@en-us |
-----------------------------------
```

If the contained string may also vary in case, consider using:

```
  filter contains(lcase(?haystack), lcase(?needle))
```

Comment: You explicitly add the values in the VALUES. How make it from the graph.?

Comment: @bib Just like you do in the question; you just use the graph pattern `?s rdfs:label ?description`.  You didn't provide any sample data, so I used a `values` block to get some bindings for `?s` and `?description` instead. But the important part is the `filter`.  If you share some of your data, it might become clear what's not working in your case.